# Посчитать значения в массиве и вывести в переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив, допустим такой:

```
var arr = [// Кол-во | множитель
    ['12', '2'],
    ['20', '3'],
    ['2, '1']
];
```

Можно ли посчитать так:

> (12 * 2) + (20 * 3) + (2 * 1)

И получить результат в переменную, допустим:

```
var arrsum = *result* //86
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = [// Кол-во | множитель
    ['12', '2'],
    ['20', '3'],
    ['2', '1']
];

console.info(arr.map(a => a.reduce((a, c) => a * +c, 1)).reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0));
```

Ох как много ответов сразу.
Себя удалять не буду!

Comment: поздравляю с 14000

Comment: На финишной прямой к Защите! :) Благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var arr = [// Кол-во | множитель
    ['12', '2'],
    ['20', '3'],
    ['2', '1']
];

console.log(
  arr.reduce((res, item) => res + item[0]*item[1], 0)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = [
  ['12', '2'],
  ['20', '3'],
  ['2', '1']
];
var m = arr.map(function(x) {
  return parseInt(x[0]) * parseInt(x[1]);
});
var arrsum = m.reduce(function(acc, val) {
  return acc + val;
});
console.log(arrsum);
```